# Doing a project for a CALC II class, and need help determining if we have sufficiently solved a product problem.

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, products

We finished our final in Calc II, and now we are doing math projects to pass time until the semester ends.

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1bYMKfCqcc9zG32Zs_Wti2Fp9rXV7Nbt4QxR3Vnp33Dc

As you can see, we must prove our product to be zero. Can anyone tell me if we are missing a sufficient part to really prove if they equal zero? Or just advice that could help make my little project more involved? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The document is not open. Try formating it directly to the question.

Comment: I'd suggest deleting this post and post another question with the doc formatted in.